# VARselect() dependence on lag.max

Tags: r, var

I am considering a VECM for two time series (loans outstanding and central bank reserves). My dataset consists of 106 observations of monthly data.

To determine the appropriate lag length, I consider using the VARselect() function from the vars package. A natural choice for the option lag.max would be 12, representing one year.

However, I noticed that the result depends heavily on the value of the max.lag option. Here are three examples:

```
> VARselect(data, type = "trend", lag.max = 12)
$selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     7      6      1      7 

> VARselect(data, type = "trend", lag.max = 10)
$selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     9      7      1      9

> VARselect(data, type = "trend", lag.max = 6)
$selection
AIC(n)  HQ(n)  SC(n) FPE(n) 
     6      1      1      6
```

As far as I understand the function, this happens because the sample size changes according to lag.max as the VAR(p) are all estimated based on the same sample size.

An alternative approach that I have tested is to estimate a VAR(p) for each lag and then calculate the responding AIC and BIC. This would then however imply that I compare models with different sample sizes.

My questions are thus:

1. Is there an objective approach to determine the maximum number of lags considered?
2. Do these strongly different results suggest problems in my data?

Comment: Same for me. You have 106 observations, therefore compared to lag.max=12 you add roughly 2% of observations with lag.max=10 and 6% of observations with lag.max=6. Have you looked the source code? You could simulate additional data and check if, e.g., with 100 times your observations the results remain the same when lag.max changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VARselect depends on lag.max. The higher lag.max, the higher the n. of initial observations sacrificed to build the regressors.

The function description says: "The function returns infomation criteria and final prediction error for sequential increasing the lag order up to a VAR(p)-process. which are based on the same sample size."

For example:

```
data_bis = data[-c(1,2),]
VARselect(data_bis, type = "trend", lag.max = 10)
$selection
```

returns the same result as

```
VARselect(data, type = "trend", lag.max = 12)
$selection
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally for time series such as ARIMA you can consider to look at ACF and PACF plots: PACF can help you to identify the lag period. Good examples and discussion is here- If they can be applied to VECM.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134487/analyse-acf-and-pacf-plots